# static object memory release

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

My Questing is

```
-(ABC*)createInstance
{
  Static ABC *obj = [[alloc ABC] init];

  if(obj == nil)
  {
    obj = [[alloc ABC] init];
  }
  return obj
}
```

can we write in objective c

```
[[ABC createInstance] release]
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense and does not compile.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve with the code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, users could release your instance if you haven't overridden `retain`/`release`. Take a look at [common singleton patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like) for better approaches.

*Notes:*

- It is `[ClassName alloc]`, not `[alloc ClassName]`
- If you meant to make `createInstance` a class method use `+ (ABC*)createInstance;`
- It is `static`, not `Static`
- You have to initialize `obj` to `nil`
- Use `self` instead of `ABC` if subclassing is a concern: `[self alloc]`
- The common name for these methods is `sharedInstance`

Comment: I'd add:
1. You **must** initialize the static storage variable with nil (non-primitives do not work).
2. You should use `self` instead of `ABC` for allocation (for subclassing).
3. The accessor should be named `sharedInstance` (common objc style).

Comment: @Nik: Good additions, but 1. only applies for file scope variables.

Comment: 1. Oh, good, I wasn't aware of this difference. 2. It should be `[self alloc]` since it's a class method (of course).

Comment: @Nik: Nevermind regarding 1., that was one of my C vs. C++ confusions :/

Comment: Yes, after looking into http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1336.pdf (and testing using gcc), I find that static storage duration variables in function local scopes can only be initialized with integral values.